# Static Ghost Blog using Buster: Wrong Image Extension

Tags: static, github-pages, ghost-blog

On local everything is working, but when I upload the static files to GitHub, Buster generates wrong image path. View this picture:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5UI0.jpg)

Thats the exact guide Ive followed to install my static Ghost Blog using Buster and Github Pages:
https://github.com/paladini/ghost-on-github-pages-1

Heres MY Github Repo:
https://github.com/paddy420Smokers/cannalogie

Ive added this to my deploy.sh

```
    find static -name *.html -type f -exec sed -i '''s#. 300w#''.jpg 300w''#g' {} \;        
    find static -name *.html -type f -exec sed -i '''s#. 600w#''.jpg 600w''#g' {} \;        
    find static -name *.html -type f -exec sed -i '''s#. 1000w#''.jpg 1000w''#g' {} \;
    find static -name *.html -type f -exec sed -i '''s#. 2000w#''.jpg 2000w''#g' {} \;
```

Hopefully someone can help me fix the issue. Im using a Mac

Answer (score 0):

You [source code](https://github.com/paddy420Smokers/cannalogie/blob/555ba5d11cad5a928343fee1ce42f96940e9f5b4/tag/getting-started/index.html#L96-L100) already include some problematic extensions:

```
<a class="post-card-image-link" href="../../welcome/">
    <img class="post-card-image" srcset="../../content/images/size/w300/2019/08/minion.jpg 300w,
               ../../content/images/size/w600/2019/08/minion.jpgg 600w,
              ../../content/images/size/w1000/2019/08/minion.jpgpg 1000w,
             ../../content/images/size/w2000/2019/08/minion.jpgjpg 2000w" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 400px, 700px" src="../../content/images/size/w600/2019/08/minion.jpg" alt="aHuh">
```

The `sed` expression is strange, and does not seem to recognize `#` as a valid delimitor.

Try `sed -i "s,. 300w,.jpg 300w,g"`, but first, you would need to fix your extension in your local code, before sending it to GitHub.